# How to remove apostrophe from List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, spyder

I'm developing a machine learning program with Python but I'm having an issue with the line of code below

```
 [['23,24,-23,12,32,54,64,12,4,0,13,10']]
```

I want to transform this data with LinearDiscriminantAnalysis But I want the apostrophe to be removed. 
I want my output to be:

```
[[23,24,-23,12,32,54,64,12,4,0,13,10]]
```

I do not what the ' before and after [ ].
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Remove the outer quotations marks as shown in the duplicate question.  This requires a `split` operation.  This will leave you with a list of strings: `["23", "24", ...]`.  Convert each of  those items to `int`, and you'll have the list you want.

Comment: `[[int(x) for x in '23,24,-23,12,32,54,64,12,4,0,13,10'.split(',') if x.strip()]]` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In[2]: a = [['23,24,-23,12,32,54,64,12,4,0,13,10']]
In[3]: result = []
In[4]: for sublist in a:
  ...:     for elem in sublist:
  ...:         result.append([int(b) for b in elem.split(',')])
  ...: 
In[5]: result
Out[5]: [[23, 24, -23, 12, 32, 54, 64, 12, 4, 0, 13, 10]]
```